# How to jsHint two different folders with Webpack?

Tags: testing, webpack, build, jshint, webpack-3

In short, I need to jshint tests specifications in parallel with the package sources during the build process.

Using the Webpack 3, how to make `jshint-loader` to watch out for two different folders with two different `.jshintrc` files? One pack of sources with `.jshintrc` is in the `./src` folder, which is bundling to the end distributive, and the other one pack with another `.jshintrc` is in the `./test` folder, which does not mentioned in the Webpack config (Karma handles it).

I tried the following two approaches, and both of them processed `./src` only, they didn't do anything with `./test`.
First version of Webpack config:

```
entry: {
    'ui-scroll': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/ui-scroll.js'),
    'ui-scroll-grid': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/ui-scroll-grid.js')
},    
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        use: [{ loader: 'jshint-loader' }]
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../test'),
        use: [{ loader: 'jshint-loader' }]
      }
    ]
},
// ...
```

The second version of Webpack config differs in the module-rules part:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../test')
        ],
        use: [{ loader: 'jshint-loader' }]
      }
    ]
},
// ...
```

But as I said this doesn't work. Full config/sources could be obtained from [this repository](https://github.com/BitDen/ui-scroll). So is it possible to fix my approach or do I need try something quite different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research we were able to solve this issue by splitting the situation into two parts: jshinting tests during production build (only once, the distributive is on the disk) and during development processes (watch mode, the distributive is in memory).

**1. Production build.** This is pretty simple, because jshit should be executed only once. After adding `jshint` as a dependency to the npm-package –

```
npm install --save-dev jshint
```

it could be prepended to the build script –

```
"hint-tests": "jshint --verbose test",
"build": "npm run hint-tests && npm run prod-build && npm run prod-test"
```

None of `prod-build` and `prod-test` processes know about `jshint`.

**2. Development.** The solution is to add a new entry point via [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob):

```
entry: {
  'ui-scroll': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/ui-scroll.js'),
  'ui-scroll-grid': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/ui-scroll-grid.js')
  'test': glob.sync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test/*.js')) // development only!
}
```

It should be done only for the development environment otherwise you'll get an extra bundle in the distributive folder. So we have it in memory; it's affecting the dev processes a bit due to extra bundling, but the difference is insignificant due to this occurs in-memory only. Then using [jshint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-loader) let's add one more rule to the module section of the webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
    },
    { // this is both for prod and dev environments
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: [{ loader: 'jshint-loader' }]
    },
    { // this is only for dev environment
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test'),
      use: [{ loader: 'jshint-loader' }]
    }
  ]
}
```

There may be too many logs in the console output, especialy during the dev-server work, so it could be helpful to limit output via `stats` property:

```
  stats: {
    modules: false,
    errors: true,
    warnings: true
  }
```